# How can I obtain another process' ASLR slide on OS X?

Tags: c, macos, aslr

Is it possible to obtain a running process' ASLR slide on OS X?

I don't want to somehow disable ASLR (eg. like `gdb`), but rather get the offset.

Example:

```
$ cat > test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int test(void) {
    return 42;
}

int main(void) {
    getchar();
    printf("%p: %d\n", test, test());
    return 0;
}
$ gcc test.c -o test
```

Running test multiple times will confirm that indeed `test()` has a different address at each run:

```
$ ./test
^D
0x104493e50: 42
$ ./test
^D
0x106fe8e80: 42
```

Note: the method to find the slide shouldn't search the memory of the process or otherwise inspect it, as I need a portable solution working for all executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the functions `find_main_binary` and `get_image_size` from `Attach.mm` in the source code of [MachOView](https://github.com/gdbinit/MachOView), you can get the ASLR slide of the process if you have the process' pid and you have root privileges like so:

```
pid_t pid = ...;

mach_vm_address_t main_address;
if(find_main_binary(pid, &main_address) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to find address of header!\n");
    return 1;
}

uint64_t aslr_slide;
if(get_image_size(main_address, pid, &aslr_slide) == -1) {
    printf("Failed to find ASLR slide!\n");
    return 1;
}

printf("ASLR slide: 0x%llx\n", aslr_slide);
```

I have made this into a small utility called [get_aslr](https://github.com/Tyilo/get_aslr).

Answer (score -2):

No, that would defeat the purpose of ASLR.

Comment: Not even with root privileges or with a kernel extension loaded that could forward it to a frontend? Seems **VERY** unlikely.

Comment: Well, you _could_ write a LKM that examines the memory space of the process. Determines where the non-aslr function would be located, finds said location in memory and calculates the offset. But you said you didn't want to examine memory. I'm having a hard time seeing the use case in this?

Comment: I'm writing a frontend to [hydra](https://github.com/gdbinit/hydra), which pauses specific executables on execution and notifies the frontend. The frontend can then patch the memory of the process w/o breaking codesigning. If you could determine the ASLR offset automatically, it would be way better.

Comment: I'm not sure, this is beyond my expertise. Good luck!